# lex/bison program to evaluate an expression

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

The following is yacc code:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
%}
%token NUMBER
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%%
statement:expression {printf("Answer=%g\n",$1);}
;
expression:expression'+'expression {$$=$1+$3;}
|expression'-'expression {$$=$1-$3;}
|expression'*'expression {$$=$1*$3;}
|expression'/'expression {if($3==0)
yyerror("Divide by Zero");
else
$$=$1/$3;
}
|'-'expression %prec UMINUS {$$= -$2;}
|'('expression')' {$$=$2;}
|NUMBER {$$=$1;}
;
%% 
int main(void)
{
printf("Enter the Expression");
yyparse();
printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
int yyerror(char *error)
{
printf("%s\n",error);
return 0;
}
```

The following is lex code:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
#define YYSTYPE double
extern int yylval;
%}
%%
[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+   { yylval=atof(yytext); return NUM;}
'\n'                    { return 0;}
'\t'                    {}
.                       {return yytext[0]; }
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I compiled both lex and yacc code. There are no explicit errors except a few warnings. But when I run the executable file it shows no value but 0.000000.

Comment: Why does the rule for line feed return zero? Or indeed anything? It's whitespace. Noise. Non-significant to the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define YYSTYPE double
extern int yylval;
```

So which is the semantic type, `int` or `double`?

Since you use `atof` and `printf("%g", $$)`, I suppose your intent is that the semantic type be floating point. But your declarations don't accomplish that:

- Defining the macro YYSTYPE only has effect in the parser. The scanner never uses that macro. In the parser, the default type is `int`.
- `yylval` is declared in the parser (as type `YYSTYPE`, according to the definitions in that file). So it is definitely an `int` and the `extern` declaration in the scanner is right, but undesired.
- Using the format code `%g` to print an `int` is undefined behaviour. The fact that all numbers seem to print as 0.0 is not surprising, but then with UB no behaviour is surprising. This might be one of the warnings you are ignoring, if you even enabled compiler warnings when you compiled your parser. You should enable these warnings and take them seriously; that habit will help you solve your own problems.

Comment: @abhilash: i don't believe you read my answer before making those changes. By the way, changing your question after it is answered is discouraged because it may make the answer wrong or irrelevant. I changed the `%lf` in my answer to match your edit, but please don't get into the habit of making such changes to your questions.